# Mac OS Catalina "Move to Bin" shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, macos-catalina

I'd like to add the shortcut `Ctrl+Delete` to the Command `Move to Bin`.

I open `System Preferences -> Hardware -> Keyboard -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Application Shortcuts -> Finder`
but when I press "Ctrl+Delete" in the "Keyboard Shortcut" textField, no shortcut is shown there.

[image]

Is it possible to assign a shortcut by editing some configuration file?

Comment: Shortcuts won't let you use certain keys or combis - backspace is one of them. idk if there's a way round that, sorry.

Comment: The shortcut "Ctrl+Delete" worked on Mac OS 10.14.  Do you mean that this feature was removed in MacOS Catalina?

Comment: I just tested it on Mojave. You've never been able to use certain keys, delete/backspace being one [two] of them. What's wrong with just sticking to the built-in Cmd/backspace like everyone else? It's not just used for delete, but for 'don't save' in dialogs, & plus shift empties the trash. they're all tied together.

Answer (score 1):

This worked:

```
defaults write com.apple.finder NSUserKeyEquivalents -dict-add 'Move to Bin' '@\U007F'
```

Comment: The answer could be made generic and better if you could description of how we can bind the code of each button